# I lost all my purchased add-ons on my PS4?

Tags: ps4, little-big-planet-2, little-big-planet, little-big-planet-3

So my sister and cousin, we play this game called "Little Big Planet 3" and we bought 3 items/costumes from the store last year. This year, we had now figured out that we could transfer our Little Big Planet and Little Big Planet 2 costumes and data all over into Little Big Planet 3.

We got excited waited, and poof everything was added. But then we realized all our purchased items were gone, it said:

> "Sorry, you cannot use this object because you don't own it (or part of it). You will need to purchase the following content from the LittleBigStore: Final Fantasy®VII Costume Pack. Thank You".

We have proof that we used these costumes since last year? What happened?

In my transaction history, nothing about the items I purchased are there? It all just vanished! I tried the Restore Licensed thing and that didn't work.

How are we able to restore our lost purchases?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade SE. Did you get your money back? Have you tried to contact the support? You should still have an email with the bill of this buy somewhere if you haven't deleted it.

Comment: have you tried redownloading it as unless your either on the wrong account or it was removed from you account you should be able to redownload anything you have brought from the Playstation Store

Comment: Is it possible that this dlc inst offered as new anymore?  That can happen with cross branded dlc i.e. dlc that involves property of another company.  The license can only be transferred in a certain amount of time typically.  Your best bet is to contact Sony support.

Comment: Are you logging in with the same PSN account playing LBP3 that owned the original content on LBP1 & 2? Also, did you play LBP1 & 2 on PS3 or PS4?